# Dative case instead of für?

Tags: preposition, dative, grammar-identification

Example sentence:

> Die Wegbeschreibung, die ich mir der Einladung zum Vorstellungsgespräch bekommen habe, ist sehr gut.

The *der Einladung* seems to be of Dative case, but I failed to understand this grammar structure here. Would it be better to just use *für*, i.e.

> ..., die ich mir für die Einladung zum...? (like in English)

Another minor point, as I feel, Dative Case can be translated as "to you; at you; for you; in you"; that said, the 3rd object in a sentence. For example, *Ich schickte dem Mann(e) das Buch*. But this point seems less relevant because the subject is already "ich". Does the meaning change if I don't use "mir" in this sentence?

Comment: This might just be a typo. "Die Wegbeschreibung, die ich mi**t** der Einladung zum Vorstellungsgespräch bekommen habe" makes more sense to me.

Comment: This surely is a typo. With "mir", the sentence doesn't make sense at all. It must be "mit". (native speaker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments that's a typo. The sentence with next to 100% certainty is supposed to be "The directions, that came with the invitation for the interview, are pretty good.". So it should be "mit" and not "mir". Your attempt to save it "..., die ich mir für die Einladung zum..." would still sound better without the "mir" but it would also imply that you got directions for the invitation whereas it's more likely that the directions where part of the invitation and direct you on how to get to the interview.